# DeflaterOutputStream: write beyond end of stream

Tags: java

I get dealt a "write beyond end of stream" error by deflaterstream. I tracked the error down, and it shows the stream is apparently finished already. However, at the beginning of my function is create the stream as brand new and do not call close or finish at the very end ..

Error:

```
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: write beyond end of stream
    at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:102)
    at evidence.SaveStateManager.saveIncremental(SaveStateManager.java:82)
```

Code:

```
public static void saveIncremental(int textureId, int layer, int shot) {
    try {
        bOut = new FileOutputStream("saves/p-" + layer + "-" + shot + ".gz");
        gzipOut = new DeflaterOutputStream (bOut, deflater);

        glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

        int bpp = 4; 
        ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(SAVE_WIDTH * SAVE_HEIGHT * bpp);
        glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
            int len = Math.min(buffer.remaining(), bytes.length);
            buffer.get(bytes, 0, len);
            try {
                gzipOut.write(bytes, 0, len);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SaveStateManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glPopAttrib();

        gzipOut.finish();
        gzipOut.close();
        bOut.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SaveStateManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Deflator is stateful and you are reusing it.

```
gzipOut = new DeflaterOutputStream (bOut, deflater);
```

from the source for DeflaterOutputStream

```
public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
    if (def.finished()) {
        throw new IOException("write beyond end of stream");
```

Comment: I don't understand the use of finish(), doc states "Use this method when applying multiple filters in succession to the same output stream." For instance if I've a source that has 5000 records, I want to compress 1000 records and dump it in a file, shouldn't I call finish() for each 1000 records I get? But the problem is if I clear the contents of underlying stream (ByteArrayOutputStream) after dumping the first 1000 records, consecutive files aren't decodable (I think GZIP header is lost), I get something like this "cannot decode raw data" Whats the right way to reuse both streams?

Comment: @NiranjanSubramanian Classing finish() doesn't allow you to reuse the underlying buffer. It means you will have written enough data for read what you have written.